# React native android browser open url in app

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, react-navigation

I have to make sure that since I'm on the browser (for example Firefox and Chrome) and I'm on a specific url, I can open in the app, then pass url to the app to be able to open a specific page on react-native.

I have the following urls:

1. `https://wwww.domain.com/page.html`
2. `https://wwww.domain.com/detail/name`

I have to make sure:

- if I have a url of type 1) then I open a specific page for react-native.
- if I have a url of type 2) then I open another specific page for react-native.

```java
<data
             android:host="www.domain.com"
             android:pathPrefix="/"
             android:scheme="https" />
<data
             android:host="www.domain.com"
             android:pathPrefix="/detail"
             android:scheme="https" />
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: I think what you require is deep linking functionality. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/

Comment: @KarthikSuthan: Would it be possible to do this without using expo or expo modules?

Comment: kindly check official documentation  https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking